# Data loss issues when trying to connect multiple ble units at once

Tags: python, window, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm implementing ble communication using my own hardware with built-in bluenrg-lp module. On my pc(window10), I used Python bleak library to implement code that stores data that is notified and code that monitors data as a graph. I am currently communicating with two ble devices, and when only one ble device is connected, data is stored normally, but data comes in unstable from the moment I connect two ble devices, and the result of storing data shows that the number of data stored by the two ble devices is different. For a simple example, when you connect two ble devices to store data, one stores 800 data and the other 400 data. I also checked the data in real time with graphs and found that the data became unstable from the moment we connected the two ble units (this was confirmed by adding indexes)
Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

What I tried was

1. Maximize the tx power of the ble device
2. Set the connection interval to be the same as recommended in the datasheet.
   But these attempts didn't work. I also confirmed that data does not always come in unstable, and that data comes in well when the signal of ble device is stable. But this instability is a serious problem in my system.

The MAX_ATT_MTU_CONF value is set to 1000 bytes and both the maximum and minimum values of the advertising interval are set to 30 ms. The data uses the aci_gatt_srv_notify function to notify about 30 bytes of data at a time.

Below is part of my python code.

```
class BLE:
def __init__(self, address):
    #self._client = BleakClient(address)
    self._client = None
    self._connect = False
    self._address = address
    self.index = 0
    self.roll = 0 
    self.pitch = 0
    self.emg = 0
    self.emgQueue = queue.Queue()
    self.rollQueue = queue.Queue()
    self.pitchQueue = queue.Queue()
    self._data_lock = Lock()
    self._connect_lock = Lock()

@property
def data_lock(self):
    return self._data_lock
   
@property
def client(self):
    return self._client

@property
def connect(self):
    return self._connect

@connect.setter
def connect(self, value):
    self._connect = value

@property
def address(self):
    return self._address
     

def Data_Notify(self, sender:int , data:bytearray):
    with self.data_lock:
        data = data.decode()
        #print(f"emg,roll,pitch: {data}")
        check_data = False    
        try:
            index, data = data.split(':')
            data = data.split(',')
            self.index = index
            self.emg, self.roll, self.pitch = data
            check_data = True 
            if check_data == True:
                # if int(emg) <= 4096 and int(emg) >= 0:
                #     self.emg = int(self.emg)
                # if float(roll) >= -180 and float(roll) <= 180:
                #     self.roll = float(self.roll)
                # if float(pitch) >= -180 and float(pitch) <= 180:
                #     self.pitch = float(self.pitch)
                self.index = int(self.index)
                self.emg = int(self.emg)
                self.roll = float(self.roll)
                self.pitch = float(self.pitch)
                
                if not self.emgQueue.full() and not self.rollQueue.full() and not self.pitchQueue.full():
                    self.emgQueue.put(self.emg)
                    self.rollQueue.put(self.roll)
                    self.pitchQueue.put(self.pitch)
        except:
            pass


async def start(self):      # 반복실행 해야쥐
    while True:
        if not self._connect:
            try:
                async with BleakClient(self._address, timeout=5) as self._client:
                    print(self._address, 'connected!')
                    self._connect = True
                    await self._client.start_notify(charcteristic_uuid, self.Data_Notify)  
                    while True:
                        if not self._client.is_connected:
                            await asyncio.sleep(5)  
                        time.sleep(0.01)
                        

                print(self._address, 'disconnected!')       # 여기오면 disconnect
                self._connect = False
    
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        time.sleep(1)
                    
async def check_connect(self):      # 연결됐다가 끊겼을 때
    while True:
        #self._connect = self._client.is_connected
        if  self._connect:
            if self._address == SUBIN_BLE1: 
                socketio.emit('connect1', self._address)
            elif self._address == SUBIN_BLE2:
                socketio.emit('connect2', self._address)
                
        else:       # self._connect = False
            if self._address == SUBIN_BLE1:
                socketio.emit('disconnect1', self._address)
            elif self._address == SUBIN_BLE2:
                socketio.emit('disconnect2', self._address)

        time.sleep(1)

ble1 = BLE(SUBIN_BLE1)  
ble2 = BLE(SUBIN_BLE2)  
    
def BLE1_start():   
    asyncio.run(ble1.start())
    

def BLE1_check():
    asyncio.run(ble1.check_connect())

def BLE2_start():   
    asyncio.run(ble2.start())

def BLE2_check():
    asyncio.run(ble2.check_connect())

DataReadThread1 = threading.Thread(target=BLE1_start, daemon=True)
DataReadThread1.start()

BLECheckThread1 = threading.Thread(target=BLE1_check, daemon=True)
BLECheckThread1.start()

DataReadThread2 = threading.Thread(target=BLE2_start, daemon=True)
DataReadThread2.start()

BLECheckThread2 = threading.Thread(target=BLE2_check, daemon=True)
BLECheckThread2.start()
```

[I'm monitoring data in real time using Python flask. If you look at the index graph, you can see that data is coming in unsteadily on one ble device.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXsZT.png)

Comment: Additionally, I'm using asynchronous functions and multi-threads in Python. I created two threads to read the data from each ble device.

Comment: BLE GATT notification does not guarantee data delivering. So that is more or less normal if you lost some notifications. To be sure that the data received use Indication instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am also fully aware of the limitations of wireless communication that result in some data loss. However, I want to supplement so that there is no difference in the amount of data I receive from 2 ble devices as much as possible. (Again, if 2 ble devices are connected, 1 unit works fine.) I wonder what part of the ble module should be modified to compensate for this problem and if there is anything I missed.

Comment: Last time I checked, Windows buffers up to 512 notifications. Maybe you could show your code?

Comment: @subin Would be great to see your code. Also would be great too see MTU size settlet for the devices connections.

Comment: @Emil Not always, depends on MTU and Max Notification Size set for connection.